# Nodejs API test throwing Socket Hang up error with SuperTest

Tags: node.js, http, express, mocha.js, supertest

I'm  trying to add unit tests to my nodejs application using mocha.

I've created a dummy test endpoint `'/test'` which returns a string as shown below :

**Test endpoint :**

```
app.get(routeHelper.getURLPath('/test'), (req, res, next) => {
 res.send('Helloo from test route !!');
 next();
});
```

**sample.test.js :**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
let supertest = require("supertest");
let should = require("should");

let server = supertest.agent("http://localhost:9000");

describe('Routes', () => {

  it('sample test', (done) => {

    server
      .get("/test")
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err,res){
       // console.log('***************Ressssssss*******   ', res.body);
        console.log('***************errrrrrrrrrrrrrr*******   ', err);
        res.status.should.equal(200);
        res.body.error.should.equal(false);
        done();
      });
    });
});
```

When I run the test,  it is throwing the error shown below :

```
{ Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:322:15)
at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:425:23)
at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET', response: undefined }
```

Accessing the API directly from the browser is giving the response properly. But, it's throwing this error when I run the test.

Any help to fix this will very helpful.

Comment: you are setting the agent as the host and it will expect the service is running. Make sure that that the app is running on the port.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty App is running. If I hit the endpoint in the browser, it works.

Comment: not sure what went wrong as it looks strage, only one thing I see where is use of `next();` as `send()` will call `end()` to end the the request response lifecycle. I actually need to write the same code and try it out.

Comment: @Supradeep have you ever fixed it?